# How to push the data in to one single array in react-hooks

Tags: react-hooks

As per code , i want to display the `customerNames` in a single array but as you see the image below. what is wrong here please can anyone help me thanks in advance

```
 const [names, setNames] = React.useState([]);

 socket.on('customers', function (customerNames) =>{
    setNames([...names, customerNames])
 })
  
 useEffect(() => console.log(names), [names])
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setNames([...names, customerNames])` is not recommended because it has no wrapper function, you can use it with a wrapper function like;

`setNames(names => [...names, customerNames])`